# How to refer to LinearLayout in program code?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and Android Studio. I'm trying to create a "Snake" game. I created a RelativeLayout and added two LinearLayouts to it. The first is for displaying the score, the second for the field of play and the snake itself. But when accessing the second LinearLayout via Id, I get an error. I also want to ask for help. I don't want to create a simple "snake", I'm trying to create a "beautiful" game. Like Google games "Snake". And who could help with my questions and writing code, could we go to the chat?)[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should get the reference of linear layout in activity like this

```
val llayout : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.snake)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).